# MySQL optimization. Why option2 so faster than option1

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, optimization

I wrote a query thas was taking way too much time (32 minutes) so I tried other methods to find one faster.

I finally wrote another one taking under 5 seconds
The problem is that I don't understand my optimization.

Can someone explain how it happen to be that much faster.

hugeTable has 494 500 rows

smallTable1 has 983 rows

smallTable2 has 983 rows

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE hugeTable dst,
    (
     SELECT smallTable1.hugeTableId, smallTable2.valueForHugeTable 
     FROM smallTable2
     INNER JOIN smallTable1 ON smallTable1.id = smallTable2.id
     -- This select represent 983 rows
)src
    SET dst.columnToUpdate = src.valueForHugeTable 
    WHERE dst.id2 = %s AND dst.id = src.hugeTableId;', inputId2)

-- Condition : dst.id2 = %s alone target 983 rows.
-- Combinasion of : dst.id2 = %s AND dst.id = src.hugeTableId target a single unique row.

-- This query takes 32 minutes
```

And here is a way to do the exact same request with more steps, but way faster:

```
-- First create a temporary table to hold (983) rows from hugeTable that has to be updated
cursor.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable AS 
             SELECT * from hugeTable 
             WHERE id2 = %s;', inputid)          

-- Update the rows into tmpTable instead of into hugeTable
cursor.execute('UPDATE tmpTable dst, 
                (
                    SELECT smallTable1.hugeTableId, smallTable2.valueForHugeTable
                    FROM smallTable2 
                    INNER JOIN smallTable1 ON smallTable1.id = smallTable2.id
                    -- This select represent 983 rows 
                )src 
                SET dst.columnToUpdate = src.valueForHugeTable
                WHERE dst.id = src.hugeTableId;')

-- Then delete the (983) rows we want to update
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM hugeTable WHERE id2 = %s;', inputId2)
-- And create new rows replacing the above deleled ones with rows from tmpTable
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO hugeTable SELECT * FROM tmpTable;')

-- This takes litle under 5 seconds.
```

I would like to know why the first method takes so much time. 
Understanding this will help me getting a new MySql level up.

Comment: 5 seconds to update 1000 rows out of half a million rows isn't great. But I suspect that the root problem is a lack of indexing together with the use of a subquery instead of a straightforward join. An EXPLAIN (and proper CREATE statements for all relevant tables) would tell you (and us) more.

Comment: Both table are simple without keys nor indexes.  In this question I'm not trying to be faster than 5 seconds. I want to figure out why the first method takes 32 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Add a composite index to `dst`:  `INDEX(id2, id)` (in either order).

**More**

Case 1:

```
UPDATE  hugeTable dst, 
      ( SELECT  smallTable1.hugeTableId, smallTable2.valueForHugeTable
            FROM  smallTable2
            INNER JOIN smallTable1  ON smallTable1.id = smallTable2.id 
      )src SET dst.columnToUpdate = src.valueForHugeTable
    WHERE  dst.id2 = 1234
      AND  dst.id = src.hugeTableId;
```

Case 2:

```
CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable AS 
SELECT  *
    from  hugeTable
    WHERE  id2 = 1234;
UPDATE  tmpTable dst, 
      ( SELECT  smallTable1.hugeTableId, smallTable2.valueForHugeTable
            FROM  smallTable2
            INNER JOIN smallTable1  ON smallTable1.id = smallTable2.id 
      )src SET dst.columnToUpdate = src.valueForHugeTable
    WHERE  dst.id = src.hugeTableId;
```

Without knowing the MySQL version and seeing the `EXPLAINs`, I can only guess at why they are so different...

- The subquery `( SELECT ... JOIN ... )` may or may not be 'materialized' into an implicit temp table.  (Newer versions are better at doing such.)
- Such a materialized subquery may or may not have an index created for it.  (Again, new versions are better.)
- If there are no adequate indexes on either `dst` or `src`, then the amount of 'effort' is the product of the sizes of the two tables.  Note that in Case 2, `dst` is much smaller.  (This may be the answer you are looking for.)
- If the tables are not fully cached in RAM, one could artificially involve more I/O than the other.  An I/O-bound query is often 10 times as slow as a the same query when it is fully cached in RAM.  (This is less likely to be the answer, but may be part of the answer.)
- Having a 3-table `UPDATE` would probably eliminate some of the issues above.  And it may (or may not) eliminate the timing difference.

For further discussion, please provide

- MySQL version
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- for each table
- How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
- `SHOW TABLE STATUS` -- for each table
- `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` -- for each UPDATE -- requires at least 5.6
- What percentage of the table has `( id2 = inputId2 )`?

Comment: Thank you for answering. But my question is not how to make it faster. What I want to know is why the first method shown takes 32 minutes when the second takes 5 seconds

Comment: @m_pOatrix in which case the answer is 'because you have no indexes'. A lack of indexes matters more on a table of 500,000 rows than it does on a table of 1000 rows.

Comment: I understand that. Indexes are great and useful. But I want to understand the speed difference in my 2 queries. 32 min vs 5 sec (same tables, same results). If I add indexes,  both queries will be faster but still very different from the other one.  Maybe 24 min vs 1 sec.  Can we please focus on the queries,  not on the tables.